# I want to make an UDP server/listener that runs in JBoss

Tags: jboss, udp, netty

I have to implement software that listens for UDP packets and persists their contents to a database.

It would be handy if this could run in JBoss, as this is the infrastructure we are using now.

I have seen that Netty is ideally suited to program the listener part.

Is there a way to use Netty "embedded" in JBoss? I have searched up and down the Net and the examples I have found are all for standalone listener programs.

Comment: Have you found an appropriate solution? (Ten years later... ;D)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, but you have to clarify what you mean by "*"embedded" in JBoss*". If you are writing a standard EJB application, just put Netty bootstrap code in `@PostConstruct` of singleton session bean and destroy it in `@PreDestroy`.

If it's a web application, use any servlet's `init()` method (servlet must be created eagerly on startup).

Note that EJB spec does not allow creating custom threads and listening on arbitrary ports - Netty violates both of these requirements. But JBoss won't enforce this.

Comment: ¡Thank you very much Tomasz! 

I meant a standard EJB app, as my intention is to try message driven beans to persist data from these UDP packets. 


Indeed I am aware that one shouldn't be instantiating threads and was alread researching the Connector class of Tomcat. I guess there is a way to write an UDP listener, but don't know enough yet.

If you have pointers to offer, I would be glad to Read The Fine Material that may be available. Already am devouring Netty's.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like JCA might be the appropriate path.